# Retrieve all of a user's playlist from SoundCloud limited to 50?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to retrieve all the playlists from my account via
`http://api.soundcloud.com/users/145295911/playlists?client_id=xxxxxx`, as the API reference shows.

However, I can only retrieve recent 50 playlists instead of all of my playlists. I've been looking for this but it seems like no one has had this issue before. Is there a way to get all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the section of their [API on pagination](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#pagination).

> Most results from our API are returned as a collection. The number of items in the collection returned is limited to 50 by default with a maximum value of 200. Most endpoints support a `linked_partitioning` parameter that will allow you to page through collections. When this parameter is passed, the response will contain a `next_href` property if there are additional results. To fetch the next page of results, simply follow that URI. If the response does not contain a `next_href` property, you have reached the end of the results.

Comment: Thank you! I've looked into their API again and went back to my API call response to look for `next_href` but had no luck :S However, adding the `&limit=100` showed me 100 playlists from my account so I guess they are giving out `next_href` property only for `/me/activities` API calls? Or have you had success with the `next_href` prorperties other than `/me/activities` API calls?

Comment: @ohnu93 Haven't used the API myself. I think you need to add the `linked_partitioning` parameter to get the `next_href` value (and possible register the app).

Comment: ahhh that's the trick that I did not use... That worked perfectly! Thank you for helping me resolve this issue! :D